# How do I execute code on most directories except those listed in a file with a batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

So I am trying to execute code on most directories under another except for those that I list in a text file.  So for example, if I wanted to run the code on all directories directly in C:\ but not say C:\avoidme\ I would add C:\avoidme as a line in exclusions.txt. But the code I have below does not seem to be working.  Any ideas on how this could be done?

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /b C:\') do (
 find /c "C:\%%d" exclusions.txt 
 if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
  Do code here

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    %WINDIR%\system32\find "%%d" exclude.list >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo good %%d
    ) else (
        echo bad %%d
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not work is because the entire body of the FOR DO() clause is parsed at once prior to actually executing the FOR statement. But the value of %ERRORLEVEL% is expanded at parse time, so you never get to see the updated value at execution time.

You have additional issues

- you should use the DIR /AD option to restrict the list to directories only
- you aren't interested in seeing the output of your FIND command, so you should probably redirect the output to nul

gavendkoa has one solution that will work.

Another alternative is to use delayed expansion

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /b C:\') do (
  find /c "C:\%%d" exclusions.txt >nul
  if !errorlevel! equ 1 (
    REM Do code here
  )
)
```

This has a risk in that %%d  will corrupt the value at expansion time if it contains `!`. This can be solved by toggling the delayed expansion within the loop.

Another alternative is to use the `||` operator, which means execute the following command if the previous command failed.

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /b C:\') do (
  find /c "C:\%%d" exclusions.txt >nul || (
    REM Do code here
  )
)
```

Perhaps the best option is to eliminate the need to worry about the errorlevel at all by piping the results of DIR directly to FINDSTR with the /V and /G: options to filter out values that appear in your exclude list.

The following is supposed to work

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /b C:\ ^| findstr /l /v /g:"exclude.list"') do (
  REM - Do code here
)
```

BUT - there is a nasty FINDSTR bug that can cause it to fail if you search for multiple literal strings of different lengths.

The fix is to force FINDSTR to use regular expressions instead, but then you need to escape any regular expression meta-characters that may appear in your exclusion list. For example, a directory named `myName.ext` would have to be escaped as `myName\.ext`.

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /b C:\ ^| findstr /r /v /g:"exclude.list"') do (
  REM - Do code here
)
```

Other characters that would need to be escaped within exclusion.list are `\`, `^`, `$`, `[`, `]`

Comment: I forget about **is parsed at once prior to actually executing the FOR statement**. Nice to recall this.